# haproxy & influxdb 502 bad gateway

Tags: haproxy, influxdb, grafana, telegraf

I was seeing abysmally poor performance reading from an InfluxDB Enterprise cluster. Connections to the cluster are load-balanced by haproxy. Neither the database nor haproxy were especially helpful in finding the problem. Grafana, on the other hand, at least reported http/502 (bad gateway) errors.

Answer (score 1):

It turns-out that we needed more connections (4000 were insufficient). As far as I can tell, it's not possible to set "maxconns" to "unlimited" (please correct me if I'm wrong). I bumped this up to 40000... and, voila -- system load dropped (telegraf was issuing retries/etc) and performance improved dramatically. I'm just trying to save someone some headache. You can check the number of connections on the http://$ip:$port/haproxy?stats page (see your haproxy.conf for this URI).